# Why won't createNewFile() recognize it's import?

Tags: java, file-io, import

I made this class in a NetBeans project and cannot figure out why the createNewFile method will not recognize it's import. NetBeans is giving the "cannot find symbol" error for that line. "createNewFile" is the only part underlined in red on that line. It also gives warning on "import java.io.File" saying that it is never used.

I've added try and catch blocks around the method but they make no difference. Got rid of them in the example below for the sake of simplicity.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Bleh {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    User u = new User();

    public void setUserName() {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        u.setName(in.nextLine());
    }

    public void checkForAccount() {
        createNewFile(u.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that if you want to check if a file exists, there's a method called File#exists(). Like File#createNewFile(), it also is a method of a File object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import of `java.io.File` imports *exactly that*, the class itself, into your namespace. It doesn't import all of `File`'s methods, and even if it did, there is no such method `File.createNewFile(String)`; you need to create a `File` object and call the method on it:

```
new File(u.getName()).createNewFile();
```